# Suitable plotting lib for comet technique?

Tags: javascript, graphics, plot

Could you recommend me the best plotting lib for this task? It should run on a browser (javascript or flash) and It have to let me add points from javascript code in a way like:

```
myPlot.add([x,y])
```

so I can push data from the server and have real time graphics.

Today I'm using [flot](https://code.google.com/p/flot/) (jQuery based). Where the task is not as straight as my previous example, but still works:

```
data = myPlot.getData()
data.append([x,y])
myPloy.setData(data)
myPlot.rePlot()
```

Answer (score 0):

After search for a better alternative, [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) and it's recent 0.6 version seems to be the best choice!